# Simple extractor for Quake-2 PAK archives

Tags: c, file-system

I was fiddling with the source code of [Quake-2](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-2) today and at some point wanted to extract files from the `.pak` archives used by the game. Since I couldn't find any tool to do that on my Operating System, I coded this quick-'n-dirty command line extractor for Quake-2 PAKs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// For mkdir/stat
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

/*
 * From Quake2:
 */

// Not enforced by this extractor. Was enforced by the game, we just warn.
#define MAX_FILES_IN_PACK 4096

// 4CC 'PACK'
#define ID_PAK_HEADER (('K' << 24) + ('C' << 16) + ('A' << 8) + 'P')

typedef struct
{
    char name[56];
    int filepos;
    int filelen;
} pak_file_t;

typedef struct
{
    int ident;
    int dirofs;
    int dirlen;
} pak_header_t;

/*
 * Extractor code:
 */

static void make_path(const char * path_ended_with_sep_or_filename)
{
    struct stat dir_stat;
    char dir_path[512];

    strncpy(dir_path, path_ended_with_sep_or_filename, sizeof(dir_path));
    char * pPath = dir_path;

    while (*pPath != '\0')
    {
        if (*pPath == '/' || *pPath == '\\')
        {
            *pPath = '\0';
            if (stat(dir_path, &dir_stat) != 0)
            {
                if (mkdir(dir_path, 0777) != 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "mkdir('%s', 0777) failed!\n", dir_path);
                }
            }
            else // Path already exists.
            {
                if (!S_ISDIR(dir_stat.st_mode))
                {
                    // Looks like there is a file with the same name as the directory.
                    fprintf(stderr, "Can't mkdir()! Path points to a file.\n");
                }
            }
            *pPath = '/';
        }
        ++pPath;
    }
}

static bool write_file(const char * name, const void * data, int len_bytes)
{
    // First might need the create the file path:
    make_path(name);

    FILE * out_file = fopen(name, "wb");
    if (out_file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't fopen() the file! %s\n", name);
        return false;
    }

    fwrite(data, 1, len_bytes, out_file);
    fclose(out_file);
    return true; // Assume write went OK.
}

static bool extract_file(FILE * pak_file, const char * dest_dir_name, 
                         const char * name, int file_pos, int len_bytes)
{
    void * buffer = malloc(len_bytes);
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out-of-memory in extract_file!\n");
        return false;
    }

    fseek(pak_file, file_pos, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer, 1, len_bytes, pak_file);

    if (ferror(pak_file))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file data block for %s!\n", name);
        free(buffer);
        return false;
    }

    char full_path_name[512];
    snprintf(full_path_name, sizeof(full_path_name), "%s/%s", dest_dir_name, name);

    bool result = write_file(full_path_name, buffer, len_bytes);
    free(buffer);

    return result;
}

static bool unpak(FILE * pak_file, const pak_header_t * pak_header, const char * dest_dir_name)
{
    pak_file_t * pak_file_entries;
    int num_files_in_pak = pak_header->dirlen / sizeof(pak_file_t);

    if (num_files_in_pak > MAX_FILES_IN_PACK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning MAX_FILES_IN_PACK exceeded!\n");
        // Allow it to continue.
    }

    pak_file_entries = malloc(num_files_in_pak * sizeof(pak_file_t));
    if (pak_file_entries == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out-of-memory in unpak!\n");
        return false;
    }

    fseek(pak_file, pak_header->dirofs, SEEK_SET);
    fread(pak_file_entries, 1, pak_header->dirlen, pak_file);

    if (ferror(pak_file))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading pak_file_entries block!\n");
        free(pak_file_entries);
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_files_in_pak; ++i)
    {
        const pak_file_t * entry = &pak_file_entries[i];
        if (!extract_file(pak_file, dest_dir_name, entry->name, entry->filepos, entry->filelen))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to extract pak entry '%s' #%d\n", entry->name, i);
            // Try another one...
        }
    }

    free(pak_file_entries);
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char dest_dir_name[512];
    char * ext_ptr;
    pak_header_t pak_header;
    const char * pak_name;
    FILE * pak_file;

    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No filename!\n");
        printf("Usage: \n"
               " $ %s <file.pak>\n"
               "   Unpacks the whole archive to a directory with the same name as the input.\n"
               "   Internal file paths are preserved.\n",
               argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pak_name = argv[1];
    pak_file = fopen(pak_name, "rb");

    if (pak_file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't fopen() the file! %s\n", pak_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fread(&pak_header, 1, sizeof(pak_header), pak_file);
    if (pak_header.ident != ID_PAK_HEADER)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad file id for pak %s!\n", pak_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    strncpy(dest_dir_name, pak_name, sizeof(dest_dir_name));

    // Remove the file extension, if any:
    if ((ext_ptr = strchr(dest_dir_name, '.')) != NULL)
    {
        *ext_ptr = '\0';
    }

    if (!unpak(pak_file, &pak_header, dest_dir_name))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to successfully unpack archive %s!\n", pak_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Any kind of feedback about it is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common problem with file archive extractors is vulnerability to [directory traversal attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack).  A maliciously crafted archive could contain an entry with a path like `../../../../../../../etc/resolv.conf`, which could overwrite a system file if the extraction is done by a privileged user.  You should take measures to ensure that any file you create lies within the intended destination directory.

File structures have a fixed-size representation and a pre-determined endianness.  You should use `uint32_t` instead of assuming that `int` is 32 bits.  Your treatment of `ID_PAK_HEADER` looks like it is little-endian only.

If any or all of the files cannot be extracted, you print an error message, but return a success code.  I would expect such failures to result in `EXIT_FAILURE` or some other non-zero exit status.

Consider using [`pathconf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pathconf.html) instead of hard-coding path length limits like 512.

You call `fread()` a couple of times without inspecting its return value.  It would also be better to reorder the second and third arguments so that `size` comes before `nitems`, to match the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) (even if it makes no practical difference).

Answer (score 6):

## Destination directory

Currently, you compute the destination directory like this:

> ```
> strncpy(dest_dir_name, pak_name, sizeof(dest_dir_name));
>
> // Remove the file extension, if any:
> if ((ext_ptr = strchr(dest_dir_name, '.')) != NULL)
> {
>     *ext_ptr = '\0';
> }
> ```

1. You should be using `strrchr` instead of `strchr`, because you want to remove the last period not the first.  Otherwise an argument such as `"../subdir/file.pak"` will use `""` as its destination directory.
2. You should check that the period that you find is actually in the filename portion and not the directory portion.  Otherwise an argument such as `"../subdir/pakfile"` will cause your program to use `"."` as its destination directory (after fixing #1).